# Google Maps not displaying markers from model Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am Building an app on Rails 5, Ruby 2.4.0 and trying to use Google Maps API V3.

That said, I have two locations in my locations model that I want to display on a map displayed on my locations/index.html.erb.

I followed this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example?rq=1) in hopes I could modify it to meet my needs, however to no avail. The Map its self loads, but none of the markers appear.

My api link is in my application/layout.html.erb in the head, and the following is found in my locations/index.html.erb file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var locations = [
    <% @locations.each do |location| %>
      { lat:<%= location.latitude %>, lng:<%= location.longitude %> },
    <% end %>
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
</script>
```

Essentially I was trying to loop through each location and provide the lat and lng of each location into a new marker and display on the index page map.

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated as I am really stuck here now!

Thanks.

> **EDIT #1**

[image]

> **EDIT # 2**
>   [image]
>
> **EDIT # 3**
>   [image]

Comment: Try `var locations<%= "= #{(@locations.map { |l| {lat: l.latitude, lng: l.longitude } }).to_json}".html_safe %>;` instead to see what happens. Does it solves?

Comment: What errors do you get, any in the JS console?

Comment: after trying @fschuindt recomendation, i get an error message in the console (see Edit #1 in question above)

Comment: @s1mpl3 i will update with Edit #2 to show error with original code

Comment: updates original message with original error message

Comment: What do you get when you type `locations` in console? With and without my recommendation, please.

Comment: @fschuindt see edit 3, I get this response from the console to both ways my original and your recomended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the init function from the callback otherwise your code executes before all the Google Maps JS libraries are loaded.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

In you case:

```
...
function initMap(){
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
.....
```

Comment: ok so with my code block, and sorry im still pretty crappy with js (although im learning) the example you gave above would go at the top of my script and the rest below it?

Comment: Yes wrapping all your code. But before you do that you could try adding just  function initMap(){ alert('Loaded') } so you can see what will be calling your code telling you that the needed libraries are loaded

Comment: Just keeps saying initMap is not a function

Comment: when i wrap everyting in that function it dosnt display anything at all.

Comment: Try to place the script tag that calls Google maps right after the script tag that you showed us here. And make sure it only is loaded once (remove it from were it was loaded before)